# Using Apache Rewrite Rules to Redirect Multiple Domains to Main Domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I hope I'm not being too duplicative here, but I haven't found an answer to this exact question.

Long ago, my web host tech helped me set up .htaccess for my site, and now it does not seem to be working properly anymore, likely contributing to my site losing many of its search rankings because of duplicate content and non-consolidated link juice.

I have multiple domains that I want redirected to the main domain, so that if someone tries to access domain1.com/page1.htm they are redirected to www.maindomain.com/page1.htm.

That is, I want all requests for multiple domains to be redirected to the same path on the main domain, always with the www. prepended.

Also, the secure certificate is for the non-www version of the domain, so I would like that to always be accessed without the www when it is an https request.

This is what is in the .htaccess file now, and it isn't working. Are there any errors it? Or is this correct, and apparently something else is going on preventing this code from working? And if so, what might that be?

```
RewriteEngine on
rewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.maindomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain1.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain2.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain3.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain4.com
rewriterule (.*) http://www.maindomain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you bought a cert that's for "maindomain.com" and not "www.maindomain.com", nothing in the htaccess is going to help you get around the security warning. The SSL handshake is performed *before* anything is requested so nothing on the server's end even knows what the request is for. You'll either have to buy another certificate or live with the security exception if someone tries to go to the www domain.

For everything else, try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.maindomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://maindomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```